# Continuity of Probability Measure and monotonicity

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

In every textbook or online paper I read, the proof of **continuity of probability measure** starts by assuming a monotone sequence of sets $(A_n)$. Or it assumes the $\liminf A_n = \limsup A_n$

But what about the following proof. It seems we don't need this property (monotonic).

If $\{A_i, i ≥ 1\}$ are events **(not necessarily disjoint nor monotonic)**, then

$$P [\cup_{i=1}^∞ A_i] = \lim_{m\to\infty}  P [\cup_{i=1}^m A_i]$$

This result is known as continuity of probability measures.

**Proof:**- Define a new family of sets $$B_1 = A_1, \ B_2 = A_2 - A_1,\ ..., B_n = A_n-\bigcup_{i=1}^{n-1} A_i,.... $$
Then, the following claims are placed:

**Claim 1:**- $B_i ∩ B_j = ∅, ∀i \neq j$.

**Claim 2:**- $\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ A_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^∞ B_i$

Since $\{B_i, i ≥ 1\}$ is a disjoint sequence of events, and using the above claims, we get

$$P (\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ A_i) = P(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ B_i) = \sum_{i=1}^∞ P(B_i)$$

Therefore,

$$P (\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^∞ P(B_i)$$ (a)

$$= \lim_{m\to\infty}  \sum_{i=1}^m P(B_i)$$ (b)

$$= \lim_{m\to\infty}   P(\bigcup_{i=1}^m B_i)$$ (c)

$$= \lim_{m\to\infty}   P(\bigcup_{i=1}^m A_i)$$

Here, (a) follows from the definition of an infinite series, (b) follows from Claim 1 in conjunction with Countable Additivity axiom of probability measure and (c) follows from the intermediate result required to prove Claim 2.
Hence proved.

So my original $A_n$'s were **NOT** a monotonic sequence of sets, so why do we require them to be?

Comment: What you give is what I believe the "standard" proof to be, at least from what I have seen.  It is the same as defining the monotonic sequence of sets $C_n = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$.

Comment: The $B_i$'s are not monotonic however.

Comment: Well, the $B_i$ sets are designed to be disjoint.  I think you mean the $A_i$ sets are not necessarily monotonic.  Yes, that is a good feature of doing it this way.

Comment: $\cup_1^{n} A_i$ increases to $\cup_1^{\infty} A_i$ as n increases to $\infty$, so what you are proving is not really different from the case of increasing sequences.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy OK. Now I see it clearly. Thanks man.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can first prove  $P[\cup_{i=1}^nA_i]\rightarrow P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i]$ and, as a corollary, we get that if $C_n\nearrow C$ then:
$$ P[C_n] = P[\cup_{i=1}^n C_i] \rightarrow P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} C_i] = P[C]. $$

Or,  you can first prove the fact $C_n\nearrow C \implies P[C_n]\nearrow P[C]$ and, as a corollary, we get by defining $C_n = \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$ (as in my comment) and noting that $C_n\nearrow \cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i$: 
$$ P[\cup_{i=1}^n A_i] =P[C_n]\nearrow P[\cup_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i]. $$

Answer (score 2):

I think the following is a complete proof of this theorem.

Divide the proof into 3 steps.

**Step 1**: If $\left\{ A_n \right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( A \right) $;

**Step 2** ：If $\left\{ A_n \right\} _{n=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing, we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( A \right) $;

**Step 3**: Since
$\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}\subset A_n\subset \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}$
Then $$\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k} \right) \leqslant \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) \leqslant \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k} \right) $$
And $\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}$ is increasing, $\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}$ is decreasing, so
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P} \left( \mathop {\lim\mathrm{inf}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n \right) &=\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}} \right) =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k} \right) \leqslant \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) \\&\leqslant \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k} \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k} \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}{\bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty}{A_k}} \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( \mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n \right) 
\end{align*}
Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n=A$ exists, and thus, $\mathop {\lim\mathrm{inf}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=\mathop {\lim\mathrm{sup}} \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}A_n=A$, then
$$\mathbb{P} \left( A \right) \leqslant \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) \leqslant \mathbb{P} \left( A \right) $$
which leads to $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \left( A_n \right) =\mathbb{P} \left( A \right) $.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not precise.

Firstly, the theorem needs to state that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$ exists. If $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n}$ doesn't exist, then we cannot figure out what $\mathbb{P} \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{A_n} \right)$ really is.

Comment: The infinite union of the sets $A_n$ should always exist, no? And since it is a countable union, it is also measurable.